# Google Slide - Menu options not shown after App is installed

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps-marketplace

[image]

Hi!!
I am trying to upload a plugin, I have tried it several times in my personal environment and it works correctly, but when it passes the review for approval by google it gives me the following error. How can i fix that?

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Help should not appear, my vote should appear, which is the option I am creating

Comment: What are the steps you are taking to "upload a plugin"? Upload it to where?